# Under what circumstances can I call findViewById with an Options Menu / Action Bar item?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am trying to obtain a handle on one of the views in the Action Bar. I have tried calling:

```
findViewById(R.id.menu_item)
```

but this returns null unless I call it in the onOptionsItemSelected method. I have also tried calling it from a different object:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).findViewById(R.id.menu_item)
```

but this has not worked. How can I do this?

(I am not using the ActionBarSherlock library, by the way. Also, this is **not** a custom ActionView.)

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: What code do you want to see?

Comment: Where do you want to use `findViewById`?

Comment: I don't really care - somewhere in the initialization (e.g. onCreate, onStart, onResume, onCreateOptionsMenu). I am using a Fragment for most of my code (and my main activity thus extends FragmentActivity) if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to obtain a handle on one of the views in the Action Bar

I will assume that you mean something established via `android:actionLayout` in your `<item>` element of your `<menu>` resource.

> I  have tried calling findViewById(R.id.menu_item)

To retrieve the `View` associated with your `android:actionLayout`, call `findItem()` on the `Menu` to retrieve the `MenuItem`, then call `getActionView()` on the `MenuItem`. This can be done any time after you have inflated the menu resource.

Comment: No. It's not a custom actionView - it's just a normal action bar item. The actionbar is made of views, as can be seem in the hierarchy viewer tool. When I call findViewById in the onOptionsItemSelected, it gives me the view as expected.

Comment: @Stendika: "it's just a normal action bar item" -- that is not yours to mess with. Please leave it alone. "The actionbar is made of views, as can be seem in the hierarchy viewer tool" -- it *can* be made of views, and the particular `View` mix and IDs of those views are up to Google and/or device/ROM manufacturers. They are not yours to mess with. Please leave them alone. Or, create your own action bar implementation from scratch, then use your own views.

Comment: I'm just trying to put an onLongClickListener on the actionbar item. How would you suggest doing this? Should I put it as an actionview?

Comment: It is not a recommended action but you would do this in onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) using what CommonsWare said. Find the menu item then get its view then set the onLongClickListener.

Comment: @Stendika: To be honest, I wouldn't put an `OnLongClickListener` on an action bar item. I'd go with the pattern established by `ShareActionProvider` and use a `ListPopupWindow` triggered by an `actionLayout` or `actionProviderClass`. That's more discoverable than a long-click, particularly if you use a drop-down arrow as part of the core view. That being said, if you *really* want a long-click, use an action layout, or an action view class, or an action provider. Don't rely upon internal implementations, as they are subject to change.

Comment: The guy who told me to write some code for this app says he wants one thing to happen when the button is shortpressed and something else when it is longpressed. I'll probably put it as an ActionView, as soon as I can figure out how to do that...

Comment: @Stendika: "he wants one thing to happen when the button is shortpressed and something else when it is longpressed" -- ask him how anyone will know to long-press the button, bearing in mind that users tend not to read documentation, even if the app were to supply some. There are a couple of patterns involving long-presses that users eventually figure out (e.g., to select text in an `EditText`), but I would strongly encourage this guy to come up with a better approach to the problem.